# hacer que la pagina se recargue con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Saludos buen día a todos, estoy tratando de hacer que una página en JavaScript se recargue luego de crear una galleta (cookie) para que php la pueda leer. es posible que se pregunten porque no crear la galleta desde php? esto debido a que la misma no se estaba creando en todas las veces/navegadores esto generó que se buscase hacer con js como alternativa, ahora bien al ser js código de cliente la manera para que php pueda usar la galleta que se ha creado es recargar la página.

hasta este punto, si tienen sugerencias que pueda comprobar las compruebo con todo gusto.
la idea es aprender (sobre todo si estoy cometiendo errores)

```
<script>
               //he suplantado los nombres reales
               let nomo="migalleta" 
               function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
                    let d = new Date();
                    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
                    let expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
                    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
                }
 
                function getCookie(cname) {
                    let name = cname + "=";
                    let ca = document.cookie.split(';');
                    for(let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                        let c = ca[i];
                        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                            c = c.substring(1);
                        }
                        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                        }
                    }
                    return "";
                }
 
                function checkCookie(cname) {
                    let ga = getCookie(cname);
                    if (ga != "") {
                        console.log("Estoy leyendo la galleta JS");
                        console.log(ga);
                    } else {
                        const generateId = () => Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 18);
                        ga=generateId();
                        console.log("Estoy Escribiendo una galleta JS");
                        console.log(ga);

                        // hasta este punto se imprime en la consola
                        if (ga != "" && ga != null) {
                            setCookie(cname, ga, 90);
                        }
                        //la galleta esta creada con el valor inicial y el tiempo 
                        
                        //esto no sucede
                        let url = "https://mipagina.tk/";
                        window.location.href = url;
                    }
                }

                 
                checkCookie(nomo);
                // galleta de sesion
                
</script>
```

Como pueden observar no ocurre error para el seteo o la lectura de la galleta, el detalle es que no ocurre la redirección a la página que esta en las lineas finales, cabe destacar que es una redireccion a la misma pagina (tambien probe el metodo reload) de las dos formas `window.location.reload(true);` y `location.reload(true);` tambien sin el `true`

adicionalmente me lleve este trozo de codigo a codepen.io y alli funciona, cuando digo que funciona es que hace la llamada a la pagina, claro no queda instanciada la galleta imagino porque estoy en codepen.io (ojo no se realmente si esto es por esto)

nota adicional 2: no se si esto tenga que ver, pero igual lo menciono, la página que estoy desarrollado está dentro de Wordpress

Comment: Bastante curioso, probé tu código y funcionó incluyendo la redirección a "mipagina.tk", no hay más información en consola que nos pueda ayudar?

Comment: Saludos Isaac gracias por responder, si es bastante curioso debido a que es un código de carpintería, es decir, en teoría no debería fallar. la consola no me dice nada, de hecho la pagina se muestra bien (salvo que al no hacer el proceso de recarga pues  php no conoce la galleta y lo que se hace se pierde)